# Setting NSManagedObject property stalls app... sometimes

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an app where I loop over some json and set some objects in the background

```
dispatch_async(CD_QUEUE(), ^{    

    NSEntityDescription *questionEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:QUESTION inManagedObjectContext:self.backgroundContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:questionEntity];


    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [questionsArray count]; i++) {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid == %@", questionUID];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error = nil
        NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        MYQuestion *question = nil;

        NSLog(@"Error %@",[error localizedDescription]);

        if ([array count] == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"NIL question");
            question = [self newQuestionInContext:context];
            question.uid = questionUID;
        }
        else
            question = [array objectAtIndex:0];

        if ([questionDataDictionary objectForKey:@"question"] != [NSNull null] && [questionDataDictionary objectForKey:@"question"] != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"set question %@",question);
            NSLog(@"UID: %@",question.uid);
            question.body = [questionDataDictionary objectForKey:@"question"];
            NSLog(@"set question finished");
        }

 and so on....
```

Sometimes this gets stuck at setting the question.body for the same question every time, but sometimes it completes without an issue. The question is not nil, and as you can see neither is the json object.. so what's the issue here? My app gets stuck at this point and I have no idea how to resolve this (if it happens)

logs....

`Error (null)`

`set question < MYQuestion: 0x17515e20> (entity: MYQuestion; id: 0x17641990 <x-coredata://103ACE29-9CF0-4216-BAF8-A30A04C22B0D/MYQuestion/p12493> ; data: < fault >)`

So it faults when I try to access any property on this object... There's no error fetching, but the object is sometimes in fault?? I don't understand.

Comment: You are using different contexts. Could that be a reason?

Comment: Yeah using different contexts.. though seems like not in the right way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a concurrency issue. In general, `NSManagedObjects` are not thread-safe. It means that you can only read and write their properties from a thread  in which their `NSManagedObjectContext` was created, or in this context's private queue.

You are accessing your managed objects in `CD_QUEUE`, so it's up to Grand Central Dispatch to decide in which thread this code will be executed. So there is a chance that these managed objects will be accessed from a "wrong" thread - not the one in which their `context` "lives".

Instead of `dispatch_async`, use one of `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` methods on your `context`. Their purpose is to ensure that managed objects will be accessed in a safe manner:

```
[context performBlock:^{
   //do what you did in dispatch_async block
];
```

If you want to know more about Core Data and concurrency, read a detailed (although a bit outdated) Apple's [Core Data Concurrency Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) and [Common Background Practices by objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html).

For the second part of your question: a object being a `fault` does not mean there was an error during the fetch request. It means that the object's properties have not been loaded from the persistent store (like SQLite database) to the memory yet. More on that: [Faulting and uniquing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)

Comment: Ah ok interesting... So having a specific GCD queue is inherently wrong? The reason I have it is to make sure Core Data processes are synchronous with each other. I'm guessing this will do the trick too, but how do I make sure that these processes are off the main thread? By creating this NSManagedObjectContext on a BG Thread, does that mean all of these context Perform blocks will be subsequently done on that thread?

Comment: If you want to make sure that Core Data processing runs outside the main thread, create a `NSManagedObjectContext` with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. All blocks will be executed in this context's private queue. I don't know if this queue runs all of them in the same thread (probably not) - it's an internal implementation detail. For sure they are being run in a "safe" way and not on the main thread.

Comment: If I only have 1 backgroundManagedObjectContext with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType then I'd hope these blocks will be synchronous. I'll give it a whirl. Many thanks

Comment: I'm also wondering what would happen if i wrap context performBlock inside my CD_QUEUE

Comment: /* asynchronously performs the block on the context's queue.  Encapsulates an autorelease pool and a call to processPendingChanges */ suggests I needn't worry.. and also I don't need if `([context hasChanges])` with a save context

Comment: You don't have to wrap `performBlock` in `dispatch_async`. This method does exactly what you want: performs blocks in a serial queue, on a background thread, one after another.